# laravel setting the third parameter of HTML::linkRoute

Tags: laravel

My code looks like this:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('profile', 'My Profile', [Auth::user()->username]) }}
```

What I want is a link to:

```
www.foo.com/profile/username
```

but the actual link I got was:

```
www.foo.com/profile?username
```

This is the code in `routes.php`

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'Profile@getProfile']);
```

I am using laravel 4.1 and can't find any solution to these. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about this one, but try `["username" => Auth::user()->username]`, "username" being the name of the variable as defined in `routes.php`.

Comment: @Andre I already tried that, it became `profile?username=username`

Answer (score 0):

You've defined in routes that the URL is profile/{username}, what is okey, so in the link you have to set the username in the first parameter.

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('profile/'.[Auth::user()->username], 'My Profile', }}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work :

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('profile', 'My profile', Auth::user()->username)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the link_to helper function instead of Html::linkRoute:

```
{{ link_to('profile/'.$username, "Go to Profile") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This workds for me:

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'Profile@getProfile']);

{{ HTML::linkRoute('profile', 'My Profile', ['username' => Auth::user()->username]) }}
```